# application.yml file Key 'dialect' is not expected here

Tags: java, spring, yaml, boot, dialect

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHxPA.jpg)

Everything worked fine when I tested 'in memory' but when I tired to set .yml file, I got this issue (Key 'dialect' is not expected here) and I cant find solution.

I checked yml on https://www.yamllint.com/ and its ok. Also if I go with application.proprties works fine. If anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

@Goran Z You need to set yaml file in proper structure , unnecessary spaces or improper structure for property access  might causes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I'm not sure where is the problem. As I said I checked my structure in  https://www.yamllint.com/

Comment: can you share your .yaml??